# Java Swing completely rounded JButton (circle outside area can't be clicked nor visible)

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jbutton

I've been trying to implement a completely free bordered JButton :

- Free shape as a border, as a solution is given in a previous thread : [Rounded Swing JButton using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423950/java-rounded-swing-jbutton)
- But the shape outside area can't be clicked
- And the shape outside area is not drawn, even by the parent class (JButton)

Is there a simple way to do it in "plain" Swing (without any 3d party library) ? Otherwise, is there a good free (open-source is better of course) 3d party library in order to do this ?

As an example, think about a Red Circle ball : the best interaction I can give to users is that it can't click in the outside area, particularly if the Ball is really big.

Thank you in advance

(I've thought of a component written from scratch with Java2D, and using the Shape contains() method in order to see if the click is good. But I would have 2 main problems :

- for giving the pressed apperance to the Shape, as well as the JButton does it => as someone noticed me below, that's not the most difficult, if I use two differents drawings/images
- for handling events (ActionListeners) as well as the JButton does it => if i inherits from a JComponent, the most difficult will be to reject (return from) the handling if we have not clicked on the good area => what is the best way to detect this eventual intersection between mouse clicking point and the area ?)

Comment: should it be a button... can't you use a JLabel with a Mouse Listener. You add an image in the Jlabel in order to make it look like a round button and change the image on hover in order to simulate interaction. On mouse down and mouse up you set also a different image and on mouse pressed you implement your button click logic. If you use circle images it should look like a button... or did I misunderstood, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: In fact, JLabel custom component would still be rectangular => and that would be a big problem for event-handling ! Particularly if the component is big enough for the user to see the problem. But I am aware that this effect, can be very difficult, if not impossible, to implement.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439112/java-custom-shape-panels for a simple example of creating a RoundButton. The code implements the "click detection" in 3 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you very much :) That's really better than the own method I related in an answer comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have three choises

1) every Custom [Look and Feels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954616/look-and-feel-in-java) have implements `Rounded JComponents`, this is safiest way how to do that confortly and maybe correctly too, part of them brings excelent output to the `Java Swing GUI` and with long `Bug` history, I'd suggest to use `Substance` Look & Feel, but is very, so sensitive to EDT

2) you can override whole (Custom `Look and Feels` already did that) [ButtonUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-custom-button-in-java/5755124#5755124), but your `UI_Delegate` will be `Look and Feel` and `Native_OS` sensitive, meaning example that link I post, works on `Windows` platform with `Metal Look and Feel`, if you want to create an cross `Platform` and cross `Look & Feel` non-sensitive, then you must to overrive all possible `Platforms` and `Look and Feels`

3) create `JComponent` with `Rounded Borders`, fill area inside with for example `GradientPaint`, and then add `MouseListener`, `MouseMotionListener`, `KeyListener` or better write own `KeyBindings` and create own `Model` for avoiding the concurency betweens linstening `Listeners`, then will be your `Custom JButton` cross `Platform` and cross `Look & Feel` non-sensitive

everything .... up to you, much luck

Comment: Thanks :) Finally I managed, using the third solution : inheriting from the JLabel subclass. But I also created a Ellipse2D.Float subclass to store the correct clicking area : that way I handle the events only if the MouseEvent#getPoint() is in the Shape area (contains() method of Shape). I think it is the most obvious way to do it.

Comment: +1 Good summary. This [article](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html) shows how to add your own UI delegate.

Comment: Thank you for this link : I'll have a look at it