# how to get rid of different locations from paint and paintImmediately

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paint

I'm working on arbitrary shaped buttons. First stage succeeded, as the buttons appear as expected.
Second stage fails, as the paintImmediately call from doClick paints to a completely different location.
I tried several ways to use AffineTransforms, but was not able to calculate the right location.

Any hint is appreciated.

What I tried is this - Buttonclass:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyCircleButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {
   public MyCircleButton(String text, double xCenter, double yCenter, double rOuter, double rInner,
         double start, double extend) {
      super(text);
      this.text     = text;
      this.xCenter  = xCenter;
      this.yCenter  = yCenter;
      this.xOffset  = xCenter - rOuter;
      this.yOffset  = yCenter - rOuter;
      this.rOuter   = rOuter;
      this.rInner   = rInner;
      this.angStart = start;
      this.angSize  = extend;
      int fontSize = (int) (rOuter * 0.15);

      this.font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize);
      this.addMouseListener(this);
      calcShape();
      calcText();
   }


   @Override
   public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
      return shape.contains(x, y);
   }


   @Override
   public void doClick(int pressTime) {
      model.setPressed(true);
      Component c = SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);
      Graphics  g = c.getGraphics();
      Rectangle r = shape.getBounds();

      if (g != null) {
         Graphics2D      g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         Point           p  = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(0, 0), getParent());
         AffineTransform t  = new AffineTransform();

         t.setToTranslation(p.getX(), p.getY());
         //         t.setToTranslation(xText, yText);
         //         t.setToTranslation(xCenter, yCenter);
         //         g2.getTransform().concatenate(t);
         g2.setTransform(t);
         paint(g);
      }
      try {
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(pressTime);
      } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      }
      model.setPressed(false);
   }


   @Override
   public int getHeight() {
      return shape.getBounds().height;
   }


   @Override
   public int getWidth() {
      return shape.getBounds().width;
   }


   @Override
   public int getX() {
      return shape.getBounds().x;
   }


   @Override
   public int getY() {
      return shape.getBounds().y;
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
      System.out.println("mouse clicked CIRCLE-BUTTON<" + text + "> at " + me.getX() + "/" + me.getY());
      doClick(50);
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D  g2        = (Graphics2D) g;
      Shape       oldClip   = g2.getClip();
      Paint       oldPaint  = g2.getPaint();
      Stroke      oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
      Font        oldFont   = g2.getFont();
      FontMetrics fm        = g2.getFontMetrics(font);
      Rectangle2D tb        = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2);

      g2.setClip(this.shape);
      if (getModel().isArmed() || getModel().isPressed())
         g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
      else
         g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
      g2.fill(shape);
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.draw(shape);

      g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
      g2.setFont(font);
      g2.drawString(text, (int) (xText + 2 - tb.getWidth() / 2), (int) (yText + 2 + fm.getAscent() * 0.35));
      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.drawString(text, (int) (xText - tb.getWidth() / 2), (int) (yText + fm.getAscent() * 0.35));

      g2.setFont(oldFont);
      g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
      g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
      g2.setClip(oldClip);
   }


   protected void calcShape() {
      Arc2D     a        = new Arc2D.Double(xOffset, yOffset, 2 * rOuter, 2 * rOuter, angStart, angSize,
            Arc2D.PIE);
      Ellipse2D e        = new Ellipse2D.Double(xOffset + rOuter - rInner, yOffset + rOuter - rInner,
            2 * rInner, 2 * rInner);
      Area      resShape = new Area(a);

      resShape.subtract(new Area(e));
      this.shape = resShape;
   }


   protected void calcText() {
      double angle = angStart + angSize / 2;
      double r     = rInner + (rOuter - rInner) / 2;
      double xOff  = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 + angle));
      double yOff  = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 + angle));

      xText = xCenter + (Math.abs(xOff) > 0.1 ? xOff : 0);
      yText = yCenter + (Math.abs(yOff) > 0.1 ? yOff : 0);
   }


   private double xCenter;
   private double yCenter;
   private double xOffset;
   private double yOffset;
   private double rOuter;
   private double rInner;
   private double angStart;
   private double angSize;
   private double xText;
   private double yText;
   private String text;
   private Shape  shape;
   private Font   font;
}
```

and Pane class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TestCirclePane extends JPanel {
   public TestCirclePane(int w, int h) {
      diameter = (int) (0.9 * (w < h ? w : h));
      Dimension s = new Dimension(w, h);

      xCenter = w / 2;
      yCenter = h / 2;
      setMinimumSize(s);
      setPreferredSize(s);
      setLayout(null);
      createComponents(this);
   }


   @Override
   public void paintChildren(Graphics g) {
      for (Component c : getComponents()) {
         if (c instanceof MyCircleButton)
            ((MyCircleButton) c).paint(g);
      }
   }


   protected void createComponents(JPanel p) {
      double r   = diameter / 2;
      double w   = r * 0.66;
      double r3o = r;
      double r3i = r - w * 0.5;

      add(new MyCircleButton("B0", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 135, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B1", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 45, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B2", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, -45, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B3", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 225, 90));
   }


   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
      super.paintComponent(arg0);
      Graphics2D g2       = (Graphics2D) arg0;
      Dimension  d        = getSize();
      Paint      oldPaint = g2.getPaint();

      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.fill3DRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height, true);
      g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      g2.drawLine(0, yCenter, d.width, yCenter);
      g2.drawLine(xCenter, 0, xCenter, d.height);
      g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
   }


   public static void createWindow() {
      JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Test - CircleButton");
      JPanel client = new JPanel();

      client.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      client.add(placeHolder("top"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      client.add(placeHolder("bottom"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      client.add(placeHolder("left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
      client.add(placeHolder("right"), BorderLayout.EAST);
      client.add(new TestCirclePane(800, 600), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(client);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            createWindow();
         }
      });
   }


   public static JComponent placeHolder(String s) {
      JLabel l = new JLabel(s);

      l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

      return l;
   }


   private int               xCenter;
   private int               yCenter;
   private int               diameter;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the trick =:O

I moved the shape creation from panel into a Layoutmanager and that sets the size and location of the buttons, which now works as expected. 
Without overloading position or size getters and of cause without paintImmediately :)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but here are my two cents:

1. Don't override `paintChildren(…)`. A JPanel will automatically repaint any component added to the panel.
2. Don't override paint(…). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent(…)` and you need to invoke `super.paintComponent(…)` otherwise you could have painting artifacts.
3. Don't override `getX(` and `getY()` those methods are used to control the location of the component on the panel.
4. I would also guess you should not override getWidth() and getHeight(). I would guess you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize()` method to control the size of the component.
5. If you are going to use a null layout, then your code is responsible for setting the size/location of each component on the panel.
6. Don't to a translation in your painting method. Painting of a component should always be done relative to (0, 0). The location determines where the component is places on the panel.
7. Don't invoke Thread.sleep() in the doClick() method. The Thread.sleep() will cause the EDT to sleep meaning the GUI can't repaint itself. Not sure why you even need to override the method.

Comment: 1. is correct. Works without
2. paint or paintComponent - both work. I started with paintComponent and tried to subclass Button instead of JButton - therefore paint()
3. without overloading all Buttons are located at 0/0 of parent.
4. nothing will be painted without overloading getWith() or getHeight() - even with preferredSize set, or overloaded. PreferredSize makes no difference.
6. using paintComponent(), painting does not work without translation. I added negative translation of position of shape.getbounds() - then first painting works.

Comment: 7. doClick is an endorsed copy of original method - sleeping is in original code. Not my invention. But without overriding doClick nothing action-related happens.

Tried all your recommendations, but nothing changed.
Stil need a way to repaint button on click-events at the right location.

Comment: 2. both work only if you know why they work. Overriding `paintComponent(..)` is how custom painting is done in Swing. 3. see point 5, 4. see point 5. the preferred size is only used by the layout manager. 6. It works fine is above suggestions are followed. 7. ok, but I'm not sure why you even need to override that method.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439112/java-custom-shape-panels/3440826#3440826 for a basic example that incorporates the above suggestions. Your code will be different because you support multiple shapes, but the basic concept should be relatively similar especially the logic related to size/location of the component.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But it does not help much. I don't know, how to calc the shape from components rectangle and I want to support any angle. So I have to go another way.  The solution was to implement my `paintImmediately()` and use 2 separate translations.  one in the `paintComponent()` which eliminates the shapes offset and another in `paintImmediately()` which translates the components position relative to the root window.  Don't know, why `doClick()` does not work.  If I use a JButton without mouse- or actionlisteners, painting of different states works anyway.   I wanted the same.

Comment: Now I use a mouse listener and call my `paintImmediately()` from `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` - and now it works as expected.  Thank you for your support!

Comment: *which translates the components position relative to the root window* - which shows you don't understand the concept of what a component is and how Swing was designed to work and goes against everything that has been suggested here. All custom painting should be done relative to (0, 0) of the component, not the root Window. Each component is then placed on the panel by using the setLocation(…) method.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the variant, that works. Again first the Button-class:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Arc2D;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyCircleButton extends JButton implements MouseListener {
   public MyCircleButton(String text, double xCenter, double yCenter, double rOuter, double rInner,
         double start, double extend) {
      super(text);
      this.xCenter  = xCenter;
      this.yCenter  = yCenter;
      this.xOffset  = xCenter - rOuter;
      this.yOffset  = yCenter - rOuter;
      this.rOuter   = rOuter;
      this.rInner   = rInner;
      this.angStart = start;
      this.angSize  = extend;
      int fontSize = (int) ((rOuter - rInner) * 0.5);

      setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, fontSize));
      this.addMouseListener(this);
      setBorderPainted(false);
      setContentAreaFilled(false);
      calcShape();
      calcText();
   }


   @Override
   public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
      return shape.contains(x, y);
   }


   @Override
   public int getHeight() {
      return shape.getBounds().height;
   }


   @Override
   public int getWidth() {
      return shape.getBounds().width;
   }


   @Override
   public int getX() {
      return shape.getBounds().x;
   }


   @Override
   public int getY() {
      return shape.getBounds().y;
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
   }


   @Override
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
      model.setArmed(true);
      model.setPressed(true);
      paintImmediately();
   }


   @Override
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
      model.setArmed(false);
      model.setPressed(false);
      paintImmediately();
   }


   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D      g2        = (Graphics2D) g;
      Paint           oldPaint  = g2.getPaint();
      Stroke          oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
      Font            oldFont   = g2.getFont();
      AffineTransform oldTrans  = g2.getTransform();
      FontMetrics     fm        = g2.getFontMetrics(getFont());
      Rectangle2D     tb        = fm.getStringBounds(getText(), g2);
      AffineTransform t         = new AffineTransform();

      t.setToTranslation(-1 * shape.getBounds().getX(), -1 * shape.getBounds().getY());
      t.concatenate(oldTrans);
      g2.setTransform(t);
      if (getModel().isArmed() || getModel().isPressed())
         g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
      else
         g2.setPaint(Color.GREEN);
      g2.fill(shape);
      g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4));
      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.draw(shape);

      g2.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
      g2.setFont(getFont());
      g2.drawString(getText(), (int) (xText + 2 - tb.getWidth() / 2),
            (int) (yText + 2 + fm.getAscent() * 0.35));
      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.drawString(getText(), (int) (xText - tb.getWidth() / 2), (int) (yText + fm.getAscent() * 0.35));
      g2.setFont(oldFont);
      g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
      g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
   }


   protected void calcShape() {
      Arc2D     a        = new Arc2D.Double(xOffset, yOffset, 2 * rOuter, 2 * rOuter, angStart, angSize,
            Arc2D.PIE);
      Ellipse2D e        = new Ellipse2D.Double(xOffset + rOuter - rInner, yOffset + rOuter - rInner,
            2 * rInner, 2 * rInner);
      Area      resShape = new Area(a);

      resShape.subtract(new Area(e));
      this.shape = resShape;
   }


   protected void calcText() {
      double angle = angStart + angSize / 2;
      double r     = rInner + (rOuter - rInner) / 2;
      double xOff  = r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(90 + angle));
      double yOff  = r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(90 + angle));

      xText = xCenter + (Math.abs(xOff) > 0.1 ? xOff : 0);
      yText = yCenter + (Math.abs(yOff) > 0.1 ? yOff : 0);
   }


   protected void paintImmediately() {
      Component       c  = SwingUtilities.getRoot(this);
      Graphics        g  = c.getGraphics();
      Graphics2D      g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      Point           p  = SwingUtilities.convertPoint(this, new Point(0, 0), c);
      AffineTransform oT = g2.getTransform();
      AffineTransform t  = new AffineTransform();

      t.setToTranslation(p.getX(), p.getY());
      g2.setTransform(t);
      paintComponent(g);
      g2.setTransform(oT);
   }


   private double xCenter;
   private double yCenter;
   private double xOffset;
   private double yOffset;
   private double rOuter;
   private double rInner;
   private double angStart;
   private double angSize;
   private double xText;
   private double yText;
   private Shape  shape;
}
```

and now the Pane class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class TestCirclePane extends JPanel {
   public TestCirclePane(int w, int h) {
      diameter = (int) (0.9 * (w < h ? w : h));
      Dimension s = new Dimension(w, h);

      xCenter = w / 2;
      yCenter = h / 2;
      setMinimumSize(s);
      setPreferredSize(s);
      setLayout(null);
      createComponents(this);
   }


   protected void createComponents(JPanel p) {
      double r   = diameter / 2;
      double w   = r * 0.66;
      double r3o = r;
      double r3i = r - w * 0.5;

      add(new MyCircleButton("B0", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 135, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B1", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 45, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B2", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, -45, 90));
      add(new MyCircleButton("B3", xCenter, yCenter, r3o, r3i, 225, 90));
   }


   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics arg0) {
      super.paintComponent(arg0);
      Graphics2D g2       = (Graphics2D) arg0;
      Dimension  d        = getSize();
      Paint      oldPaint = g2.getPaint();

      g2.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
      g2.fill3DRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height, true);
      g2.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      g2.drawLine(0, yCenter, d.width, yCenter);
      g2.drawLine(xCenter, 0, xCenter, d.height);
      g2.setPaint(oldPaint);
   }


   public static void createWindow() {
      JFrame frame  = new JFrame("Test - CircleButton");
      JPanel client = new JPanel();

      client.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      client.add(placeHolder("top"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
      client.add(placeHolder("bottom"), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
      client.add(placeHolder("left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
      client.add(placeHolder("right"), BorderLayout.EAST);
      client.add(new TestCirclePane(800, 600), BorderLayout.CENTER);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.add(client);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            createWindow();
         }
      });
   }


   public static JComponent placeHolder(String s) {
      JLabel l = new JLabel(s);

      l.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

      return l;
   }


   private int               xCenter;
   private int               yCenter;
   private int               diameter;
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

As the button with that shape does not behave like a "normal" button, I needed to add a mouse listener. To give visual feedback to a click, I used `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()`.
But when my `paintComponent()` was called from outside of the paint chain, I realized, that it did not know its (the buttons) origin.

So I thought, inside my paintImmediately is outside of the buttons paint concept. Therefore I prepared the environment, like superclass will do on normal paint operations. Well, what I thought the superclass will do. Don't know - just a guess.

So if you think, that my coding is wrong, please explain me, how to do better.